# Proof $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$ (Spivak's Calculus)

Tags: solution-verification, axioms

I am trying to prove that $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$. Spivak only defines $x$ and $y$ as numbers that obey some set of axioms, so while it seems to me that we can assume they are elements of a field, he doesn't seem to formalize this notion.

Here is what I have so far. I'll start with a simple lemma that $-(yx) = -yx$. We have: 
$$yx + (-yx) = (y + (-y))x = 0x = 0$$
and, by uniqueness of the additive inverse, we have $-(yx) = -yx$.

> We have: 
>   \begin{align*}
> x^2 - y^2 & = (x^2 + 0) - y^2 & & \text{additive identity} \\
> & = (x^2 + (xy + (-(xy)))) - y^2 & & \text{additive inverse} \\
> & = (x^2 + (xy + (-(yx)))) - y^2 & & \text{commutativity of mult} \\
> & = (x^2 + xy) + (-(yx) - y^2) & & \text{associativity of addition} \\
> & = (x^2 + xy) + (-yx - y^2) & & \text{lemma} \\
> & = x(x + y) + (-y(x + y)) & & \text{distributivity} \\ 
> & = (x-y)(x+y) & & \text{distributivity} 
> \end{align*}
>   How does this proof look?

Alternate proof based on a comment suggesting that I start from the right-hand side: 
\begin{align*}
(x - y)(x + y) & = x(x + y) + (-y(x+y)) & & \text{distributive law} \\
& = (xx + xy) + ((-yx) - yy) & & \text{distributive law} \\
& = (x^2 + xy) + ((-yx) - y^2) & & \text{definition of square} \\
& = x^2 + (xy + (-yx)) - y^2 & & \text{associativity of addition} \\
& = x^2 + (yx + (-yx)) - y^2 & & \text{commutativity of multiplication} \\
& = x^2 + 0 - y^2 & & \text{additive inverse} \\
& = (x^2 + 0) - y^2 & & \text{associativity of addition} \\
& = x^2 - y^2 & & \text{additive identity} 
\end{align*}
How does this look?

Comment: I think it would go faster if you started from the right-hand side and multiplied using distributivity twice.

Comment: This is a good point. I will write an alternate proof starting from the right-hand side (without just copying the steps I wrote above, of course). Is the proof I wrote valid, though?

Comment: I think it's OK, and I like how you have set it out with a justification of each step. If I were feeling exp(fussy) I would say that in (i) your second proof at the first associativity step you have used associativity twice, (ii) in the first proof at the first distributivity step you  have used the axiom twice.

Comment: I was a bit worried about this associativity step, yes. How should I have written a single step of it? Should I write $(a + (b+c)) + d = ((a+b) + c) + d = (a+b) + (c+d)$?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand using distributivity twice. Could you explain more? Thanks again.